# Increase in Eden Space and Old Gen peak values

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection, java-17, g1gc

After Java 17 upgrade, JVM heap memory started to increase. When we check the memory metrics, sizes of the Eden Space and the Old Generation fluctuating and peak values are increasing.

There seems no increase in lower values of Old Gen but the problem is it is increasing so fast and the peak value is also increasing.

When I inspect the memory dumps, there seems no potential leak. Can we say that there is a memory leak in here?

[image]

EDIT:
We have upgraded from Java 11 to 17.
I don't see any unusual activity in GC metrics.
[image]

Before the Upgrade Metrics:
The heap usage is much lower:
[image]

I don't see such activity in GC metrcis:
[image]

Comment: It rather seems that the GC has decided that you have a lot of short-lived objects, so it has changed the classification of +/- 28GiB of memory from old-gen to Eden.

Comment: "after java 17 upgrade"... from what? 8? If so, G1GC though can be enabled in java-8, was never recommended to do. What you see on the graphs are most probably an effect of `UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`, where G1 decided (based on previous cycles) what is old/new and how big are supposed those to be.

Comment: @Eugene I have updated the question. We have upgraded from Java 11 and we were using the default GC in Java 11 also which is G1GC I think. When I take memory dumps in different times(after the fresh deployment and 1-2 days later), nearly there is no difference in object counts, sizes or retained sizes. I don't get why peak values of Eden space and Old space is increasing.

Comment: Can you show JVM options and GC logs?

Comment: Java 11 and Java 17 both use g1gc, so the garbage collector could be the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

Identify Increased `Heap Memory Vs  Memory Leak` situation

- `Java 17` changed the default `garbage collector (GC) from Parallel GC to G1 GC`. - `G1 GC` divides the heap into smaller regions and adapts the size and number of regions based on the application's behavior & has a different way of handling young and old generations, which may affect the heap usage patterns

  To verify run your application with different `GCs` and compare the results. e.g. `XX:+UseParallelGC` option to switch back to `Parallel GC`, or try other GCs such as `ZGC or Shenandoah GC`

  Use the `-Xlog:gc` option to enable `GC logging` and analyze the GC behavior in more detail.
- If the GC is not the cause of your increased heap memory usage,  poss. `memory leak` in your application i.e. an object is no longer needed by the application, but it is still referenced by other objects and cannot be reclaimed by the GC. To detect this  use  tools such as `Eclipse Memory Analyzer`,  to analyze memory dumps